# Parallelize a rolling window regression in R

Tags: r, finance, quantmod

I'm running a rolling regression very similar to the following code:

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(quantmod)
data(managers)

FL <- as.formula(Next(HAM1)~HAM1+HAM2+HAM3+HAM4)
MyRegression <- function(df,FL) {
  df <- as.data.frame(df)
  model <- lm(FL,data=df[1:30,])
  predict(model,newdata=df[31,])
}

system.time(Result <- rollapply(managers, 31, FUN="MyRegression",FL,
    by.column = FALSE, align = "right", na.pad = TRUE))
```

I've got some extra processors, so I'm trying to find a way to parallelize the rolling window.  If this was a non-rolling regression I could easily parallelize it using the apply family of functions...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The obvious one is to use `lm.fit()` instead of `lm()` so you don't incur all the overhead in processing the formula etc.

**Update:** So when I said *obvious* what I meant to say was **blindingly obvious but deceptively difficult to implement**!

After a bit of fiddling around, I came up with this

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(quantmod)
data(managers)
```

The first stage is to realise that the model matrix can be prebuilt, so we do that and convert it back to a Zoo object for use with `rollapply()`:

```
mmat2 <- model.frame(Next(HAM1) ~ HAM1 + HAM2 + HAM3 + HAM4, data = managers, 
                     na.action = na.pass)
mmat2 <- cbind.data.frame(mmat2[,1], Intercept = 1, mmat2[,-1])
mmatZ <- as.zoo(mmat2)
```

Now we need a function that will employ `lm.fit()` to do the heavy lifting without having to create design matrices at each iteration:

```
MyRegression2 <- function(Z) {
    ## store value we want to predict for
    pred <- Z[31, -1, drop = FALSE]
    ## get rid of any rows with NA in training data
    Z <- Z[1:30, ][!rowSums(is.na(Z[1:30,])) > 0, ]
    ## Next() would lag and leave NA in row 30 for response
    ## but we precomputed model matrix, so drop last row still in Z
    Z <- Z[-nrow(Z),]
    ## fit the model
    fit <- lm.fit(Z[, -1, drop = FALSE], Z[,1])
    ## get things we need to predict, in case pivoting turned on in lm.fit
    p <- fit$rank
    p1 <- seq_len(p)
    piv <- fit$qr$pivot[p1]
    ## model coefficients
    beta <- fit$coefficients
    ## this gives the predicted value for row 31 of data passed in
    drop(pred[, piv, drop = FALSE] %*% beta[piv])
}
```

A comparison of timings:

```
> system.time(Result <- rollapply(managers, 31, FUN="MyRegression",FL,
+                                 by.column = FALSE, align = "right", 
+                                 na.pad = TRUE))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.925   0.002   1.020 
> 
> system.time(Result2 <- rollapply(mmatZ, 31, FUN = MyRegression2,
+                                  by.column = FALSE,  align = "right",
+                                  na.pad = TRUE))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.048   0.000   0.05
```

Which affords a pretty reasonable improvement over the original. And now check that the resulting objects are the same:

```
> all.equal(Result, Result2)
[1] TRUE
```

Enjoy!

Comment: @Zach I, of course presume you know what you are doing here - trying to get one-step-ahead predictions?

Comment: @Gavin Simpson Yes, that is what I'm doing.  I'm also trying to parallelize this.

Comment: @Zach - Just posted an update that contains code to implement my `lm.fit()` suggestion. Doing it was a bit more complicated than I appreciated.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson: What if I wanted to use another regression function, such as `glm` or `glmnet`?  Would I be able to implement something similar, or is your method optimized for linear regression alone?

Comment: @Zach well, there is a `glm.fit` but you'll have to arrange to call it directly in the same way I do for `lm.fit` above. The only way to do it, is to step through what a `glm()` call does using the debugger and see which steps you need to provide `glm.fit` with the relevant objects. As for `glmnet()` then a quick look suggests you can call functions that are used in `glmnet()`, but it depend which family you want. So yes, this generalises, but you just need to identify the fast fitting code you need then arrange to call it.

Answer (score 2):

## New answer

I wrote a package, `rollRegres`, that does this much faster. It is ~ 58 times faster than [Gavin Simpson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5652114/5861244). Here is an example

```r
# simulate data
set.seed(101)
n <- 10000
wdth <- 50
X <- matrix(rnorm(10 * n), n, 10)
y <- drop(X %*% runif(10)) + rnorm(n)
Z <- cbind(y, X)

# assign other function
lm_version <- function(Z, width = wdth) {
  pred <- Z[width + 1, -1, drop = FALSE]
  ## fit the model
  Z <- Z[-nrow(Z), ]
  fit <- lm.fit(Z[, -1, drop = FALSE], Z[,1])
  ## get things we need to predict, in case pivoting turned on in lm.fit
  p <- fit$rank
  p1 <- seq_len(p)
  piv <- fit$qr$pivot[p1]
  ## model coefficients
  beta <- fit$coefficients
  ## this gives the predicted value for next obs
  drop(pred[, piv, drop = FALSE] %*% beta[piv])
}

# show that they yield the same
library(rollRegres) # the new package
library(zoo)
all.equal(
  rollapply(Z, wdth + 1, FUN = lm_version,
            by.column = FALSE,  align = "right", fill = NA_real_),
  roll_regres.fit(
    x = X, y = y, width = wdth, do_compute = "1_step_forecasts"
    )$one_step_forecasts)
#R [1] TRUE

# benchmark
library(compiler)
lm_version <- cmpfun(lm_version)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  newnew = roll_regres.fit(
    x = X, y = y, width = wdth, do_compute = "1_step_forecasts"),
  prev   = rollapply(Z, wdth + 1, FUN = lm_version,
                     by.column = FALSE,  align = "right", fill = NA_real_),
  times = 10)
#R Unit: milliseconds
#R   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#R newnew  10.27279  10.48929  10.91631  11.04139  11.13877  11.87121    10
#R   prev 555.45898 565.02067 582.60309 582.22285 602.73091 605.39481    10
```

## Old answer

You can reduce the run time by updating a decomposition. This yields an [image: frm1] cost at each iteration instead of [image: frm1] where n is you window width. Below is a code to compare the two. It would likely be much faster doing it in C++ but the LINPACK `dchud` and `dchdd` are not included with R so you would have to write a package to do so. Further, I recall reading that you may do faster with other implementations than the LINPACK `dchud` and `dchdd` for the R update

```
library(SamplerCompare) # for LINPACK `chdd` and `chud`
roll_forcast <- function(X, y, width){
  n <- nrow(X)
  p <- ncol(X)
  out <- rep(NA_real_, n)

  is_first <- TRUE
  i <- width 
  while(i < n){
    if(is_first){
      is_first <- FALSE
      qr. <- qr(X[1:width, ])
      R <- qr.R(qr.)

      # Use X^T for the rest
      X <- t(X)

      XtY <- drop(tcrossprod(y[1:width], X[, 1:width]))
    } else {
      x_new <- X[, i]
      x_old <- X[, i - width]

      # update R 
      R <- .Fortran(
        "dchud", R, p, p, x_new, 0., 0L, 0L, 
        0., 0., numeric(p), numeric(p), 
        PACKAGE = "SamplerCompare")[[1]]

      # downdate R
      R <- .Fortran(
        "dchdd", R, p, p, x_old, 0., 0L, 0L, 
        0., 0., numeric(p), numeric(p), integer(1),
        PACKAGE = "SamplerCompare")[[1]]

      # update XtY
      XtY <- XtY + y[i] * x_new - y[i - width] * x_old
    }

    coef. <- .Internal(backsolve(R, XtY, p, TRUE, TRUE))
    coef. <- .Internal(backsolve(R, coef., p, TRUE, FALSE))

    i <- i + 1
    out[i] <- X[, i] %*% coef.
  }

  out
}

# simulate data
set.seed(101)
n <- 10000
wdth = 50
X <- matrix(rnorm(10 * n), n, 10)
y <- drop(X %*% runif(10)) + rnorm(n)
Z <- cbind(y, X)

# assign other function
lm_version <- function(Z, width = wdth) {
  pred <- Z[width + 1, -1, drop = FALSE]
  ## fit the model
  Z <- Z[-nrow(Z), ]
  fit <- lm.fit(Z[, -1, drop = FALSE], Z[,1])
  ## get things we need to predict, in case pivoting turned on in lm.fit
  p <- fit$rank
  p1 <- seq_len(p)
  piv <- fit$qr$pivot[p1]
  ## model coefficients
  beta <- fit$coefficients
  ## this gives the predicted value for row 31 of data passed in
  drop(pred[, piv, drop = FALSE] %*% beta[piv])
}

# show that they yield the same
library(zoo)
all.equal(
  rollapply(Z, wdth + 1, FUN = lm_version,  
            by.column = FALSE,  align = "right", fill = NA_real_),
  roll_forcast(X, y, wdth))
#R> [1] TRUE

# benchmark
library(compiler)
roll_forcast <- cmpfun(roll_forcast)
lm_version <- cmpfun(lm_version)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  new =  roll_forcast(X, y, wdth),
  prev = rollapply(Z, wdth + 1, FUN = lm_version,  
                   by.column = FALSE,  align = "right", fill = NA_real_), 
  times = 10)
#R> Unit: milliseconds
#R> expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#R>  new 113.7637 115.4498 129.6562 118.6540 122.4930 230.3414    10  a 
#R> prev 639.6499 674.1677 682.1996 678.6195 686.8816 763.8034    10   b
```